Perfusion Analysis Counts as Survival Analysis?
In perfusion analysis, the patient is injected with some dose of medicine. A machine detects, over time, the dose of medicine in the patient's body. In other words, the data for each patient is time points $0=t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_N$ and doses $y_1, \ldots, y_N$, with $y_i \in [0, \infty)$ representing the amount of dose in patient's body at time $t_i$. (Typically, $y_i$ can also be some indirect measure of doses.) Depending on scenarios, there can be only one patient or several patients or patients divided in groups, etc. We stress only one assumption: given time $t$, the dose at time $t$ for any patient is random so that this is not a machine learning task.
When we plot all the pairs $(t_i,y_i)$, the shape usually looks like a probability density function of some distributions concentrated on $[0, \infty)$ (e.x. lognormal, Weibull, exponential, ...)
The statistician's task here is typically to investigate the trend, make inference of for instance when does the dose reach its peak, when the dose ascends, etc. One way of solving the problem is to talk to the client, fit a probability density function according to beliefs, and then look at the tasks.
For example, suppose that there is only one patient and we want to give an estimate of when the dose reaches the peak. We can say fit the data with the probability density function of lognormal distribution after discussing with client, with parameter chosen to say minimize least squares, and then look at the fitted maximum.
Question: what is the name of the statistician's task? Does such task count as a survival analysis? Time series analysis? I am leaning towards calling it survival analysis but I am uncertain, for typical tools in survival analysis seems unavailable at such a scenario.

This is pharmacokinetics. It certainly is not survival analysis, which evaluates the times to events (even if the event isn't always death).
Even if the concentration versus time plot of a drug might resemble a specific probability density function, it's unwise to try to analyzed the data that way. Mathematical modeling based on the generally recognized ways that drugs are distributed among different body fluid spaces once administered and the ways that the body can eliminate or degrade the drug will be more informative and probably fit the data better. The link above provides links to software that can do such analysis.

It is stressed that by observations/beliefs the curve is a density function of a finite measure as the given data easily transforms into an empirical distribution function. The same dose of medicine may give a different $y_i$ curve by human error, individual difference or even sometimes $y_i$ itself represents averages. For example, $y_i$ could be brightness of image pixels. Therefore, it should be a statistician task rather than modeling task (which is way too difficult in practice). I do not understand why modelling the distribution based on empirical distribution function is discouraged.

@温泽海 this comes from my background in physiology and pharmacology. Pharmacokinetic modeling has been well established for a long time and is a cornerstone of the pharmaceutical industry (ADME: modeling absorption, distribution, metabolism, and excretion). The method for estimating the drug concentration from something like image pixel brightness might require some additional statistical expertise, but differences among individuals are certainly evaluated in standard pharmacokinetic analysis. Human error will be no less of a problem if you work with empirical distributions.

I guess this "additional expertise" is what I am asking for. But thank you for bringing pharmacokinetics up. I will study it a little bit although I am pretty certain modelling is not the way to go.

I don't understand the downvote. @EdM's answer is spot on (+1)
